# Excel If Functions with Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a formula that captures the following information:

- If the value in C3 is 0 it needs to read 'Green',
- the value in C3 is ≥1 but <500 it needs to read 'Silver',
- the value in C3 is ≥500 but <1500 it needs to read 'Gold' and
- if the value in C3 is ≥1500 then it needs to read 'Platinum'.

I have this formula worked out:

```
=IF(D3<500,"Silver",IF(AND(D3>=500,D3<=1499),"Gold","Platinum"))
```

but I can't figure out how to incorporate the 0 to equal Green.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
=IF(C3<=0,"Green",IF(C3<500,"Silver",IF(C3<=1499,"Gold","Platinum")))
```

I added `<=0` just in case you have negative numbers. Without it, `-1` will return `Silver`.  Also note that if `C3` is empty/blank, it'll return `Green` still.

Comment: @Eogrus - Glad to help! If this works for you, you can flag it as The Answer by ticking the check mark left of the post.